# Extracting span tag content from html page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the date and time i.e. article published at from this link - https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/tags/coronavirus.html/page-2/

```
for link in soup.findAll('span'):
        print(link)
```

This will give all span from the page.

```
<li class="clearfix" id="newslist-2">   
            <a href="https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/world/europe-should-temporarily-ban-chinese-takeovers-germanys-weber-5277251.html" title="Europe should temporarily ban Chinese takeovers - Germany's Weber"><img data="https://images.moneycontrol.com/static-mcnews/2020/05/Manfred-Weber-613x435.jpg" class="" src="https://images.moneycontrol.com/static-mcnews/2020/05/Manfred-Weber-613x435.jpg" data-src="https://images.moneycontrol.com/static-mcnews/2020/05/Manfred-Weber-613x435.jpg" alt="Europe should temporarily ban Chinese takeovers - Germany's Weber" title="Europe should temporarily ban Chinese takeovers - Germany's Weber"></a> <span>May 17, 2020 08:46 AM IST</span>    i>
```

I guess `clearfix` class item may help but I am not sure how to use it.

Can you help me to get date and time for each article?

Comment: first select all `li` with this class and later use for loop to search `link` inside every element separatelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[id^=newslist]` css selector to get all news articles and then get link and published date for each article:

```
for article in soup.select('[id^=newslist]'):
    link = article.select_one('a')['href']
    published_date = article.select_one('span').text
    print(published_date, link)
```